# Get id of any div and its childrens returned from php to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Description :**

After some php work at the end,my php returns the following output to the jquery which called this page

```
<div id = "container1">
   <div id = "chicken1"></div>
   <div id = "soup1"></div>
</div>


<div id = "container2">
   <div id = "chicken2"></div>
   <div id = "soup2"></div>
</div>
```

and so on ...

Now in the jquery call back it gets lot of results. So among the results I want to search for the divs with specific id's or get those id's. How can I do that.

e.g lets say I want all the id's that say chicken1 , chicken2 and so on .... Is there a way to do that ??

**Following Is The Code :**

**PHP**

```
echo '<div id = "container1">
       <div id = "chicken1"></div>
       <div id = "soup1"></div>
    </div>


    <div id = "container2">
       <div id = "chicken2"></div>
       <div id = "soup2"></div>
    </div>';
```

**JQUERY**

`$.post("../PHP/get_all_new_msgs_on_profile.php",{arr:data},function(result)
            {
            $(result).hide().prependTo("#new_buddy_messages_on_profile").fadeIn("fast").slideDown("slow"); }`

Now the $(result) has the divs returned by the php how can I extract the id's of the divs from it ... PLease ignore any typing mistake . thanks :)

Comment: `id` should be unique for each element.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question. _search for the divs with specific id's or get those id's_ What does that mean?

Comment: @Kristoffer I have edited my question look in the description along with code ...
I think I have made it pretty much clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Mritunjay your id's must all be unique. If you need to assign or access multiple elements by name, you should give them a class (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp)

For more info see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

jQuery selectors:

- **ID:** `$("#myId")`
- Class: `$(".myClass")`
- Element: `$("element")` - i.e. `$("div")`

For a list of all jQuery selectors see this link: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

To get the child element of a specific element, use `children()`. An example of its implementation is as follows:

```
$(".myClass").children("div"); //Assuming .myClass has a child `div` element
```

---

In your case...

**HTML**

```
<div id = "container">
   <div id = "chicken1"></div>
   <div id = "soup"></div>
</div>


<div id = "container">
   <div id = "chicken2"></div>
   <div id = "soup"></div>
</div>
```

**Should be changed to:**

```
<div class = "container">
   <div id = "chicken1"></div>
   <div class = "soup"></div>
</div>


<div class = "container">
   <div id = "chicken2"></div>
   <div class = "soup"></div>
</div>
```

and to get each element with the class `.container` assigned, use `$(".container")`
to get each child element of the class `.container` with the various id's beginning with `chicken` you can use the following:

```
$(".container").children('*[id^="chicken"]').each(function () {
    //Something here
});
```

As in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/rkfqgxpg/)

Answer (score 2):

First of all change `<div id='container'>` to `<div class='container'>` after that try using this.

```
$('.container [id*=chicken]').each(function(index){
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change all the id's to classes, because id's need to be unique.

You could use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

```
$(".container:has(.chicken2)")
```